# Improve results of image stitching using OpenCV (material science)

Tags: computer-vision, opencv

I'm trying to improve image stitching results with a series of pictures taken via microscope. The object I've photographed is a 3D printed cube that has a number of repeating shapes on the surface. The shapes are repeated so that we can measure their dimensions and perform some machine learning algorithm on the data down the road.

However, as the shapes are identical, and the printer material (resin) that forms the cube present little in the way of distinct features, image stitching performance has not been as good as hoped.

I'm at the point where I'd like to add unique features into the design itself, but haven't found much literature discussing this issue and possible solutions. Given that I'm working with the CAD software SolidWorks, I'm wondering if anyone can provide a suggestion for adding features (possibly non-repeating?) that could theoretically improve performance of OpenCV's image stitcher.

Thanks!

*Side note: these cube samples have a length/width of 25mm when printed.*